# My integral is behaving strangely

Tags: integration

The following integral is something I am trying to solve for

$$ \int_{\gamma}^{\infty} \Bigg[ 1- \left( \frac{2a(1+s x^{-1})+b}{1+s x^{-1} } \right)  \Bigg] x^{\frac{2}{\alpha}-1} \, dx$$

We have also that $$b+2a =1$$.
Let us take specific cases

1- $\alpha=2$, $a$=0.5, $b$=0;  the integral above is zero, which makes sense ofcourse

2-$\alpha=2$, $a$=0.49, $b$=0.001, the integral above is infinity... (using MATLAB)..

I must say that I did a change of variable $x=st^\alpha \rightarrow  dx= \alpha st^{\alpha-1}\,dt$ when I plugged the expression in MATLAB. If needed I can re-write the expression above in terms of $t$.

I used the symbolic integration (int) and the answer is usually in terms of $t$ and $\gamma$..

**Question**

I don't understand why a slight change of variables makes the whole thing blow up

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Well, with $\alpha=2$ the outer term is irrelevant. Is $s$ fixed? If so, then the answer is quite simple: the $b$ term is asymptotically constant, so its integral diverges if $b \neq 0$. The $1$ and the $a$ term combine to just $1-2a$, which also diverges if $a \neq 1/2$. So unless the two of them balance each other perfectly, the integral will diverge. To get convergence, you might try having $1-2a=b$, for instance $a=0.999/2$ and $b=0.001$.

Comment: I agree that for $\alpha=2$, the term is irrelevant but I kept it because I might want to try a different $\alpha$, btw $s$ is not a function of $x$, in fact after the change of variable that I noted,the term $s$ is no longer inside the integral. This is why I found this change of variable neat.

Comment: @Ian thanks, what do you mean exactly by the two of them balance each other perfectly?

Comment: @Tyrone Unless $1-2a=b$, the integrand will converge to a nonzero constant, which will cause the integral to diverge.

Comment: @Ian, I tried the example you gave me, it also diverged, do you think the problem is in the change of variable?

Comment: @Tyrone It might still diverge even if $1-2a-b=0$, I'm not sure what necessarily happens then. It should definitely diverge if $1-2a-b \neq 0$, though.

Comment: @Ian, actually the problem i am trying to solve does have a condition that $2a+b=1$ so I wasn't surprised you said that, however I still have a divergent integral.. so weird

Comment: @Ian if we have that $1-2a-b=0$, the integrand can be re-written as $(1-2a)\frac{2+sx^{-1}}{1+sx^{-1}}$, is this a divergent integrand?

Comment: @Tyrone It looks like it is, unless in addition you have $1-2a=0$ of course. Because again that will converge to a nonzero constant (specifically, $2-4a$).

Comment: Is it possible that with $\alpha=3$ the integral would not diverge with the condition $1-2a-b=0$ @Ian... i.e is $\alpha=2$ a very special case

Comment: @Tyrone No; you'd need the exponent on the outer $x$ to be less  than $-1$ to get convergence, given that the inside is converging to a nonzero constant. And this is impossible if $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: actually i tried it using MATLAB for $\alpha=3$ it worked fine @Ian with $a=0.999/2$ and $b= 1-2a$; can you please try the change of variable, maybe this is helping...

Comment: @Tyrone Apparently I made an error; the inside is on the order of $1/x$, so you'll get convergence whenever $\alpha > 2$. Cf. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%280.999%281%2Bx^%28-1%29%29%2B0.001%29%2F%281%2Bx^%28-1%29%29

Comment: awesome thanks @Ian

Comment: can you also give me your opinion about this [otherquestion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118431/is-my-integral-diverging-or-converging), i would really appreciate it. @Ian

Comment: @Ian about your last note, is the inside on the of $1/x$ or $x$?

Comment: may I please have your intuition[for this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118431/for-what-values-is-my-integral-diverging-or-converging), there are two opposing answers and can't see to know which is correct @Ian ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $1-2a-b=0$, then the inside is on the order of $x^{-1}$. Basically this is because you can rewrite it as

$$\frac{(1-2a)(1+sx^{-1})-b}{1+sx^{-1}} = \frac{(1-2a)sx^{-1}}{1+sx^{-1}}$$

Now as $x \to \infty$ the numerator is on the order of $1/x$ while the denominator is on the order of $1$. So with $\alpha=2$ your integrand is on the order of $1/x$, so you get divergence; if $\alpha > 2$ it is on the order of $x^c$ for $c<-1$ so you get convergence. (To make this formal you should actually write comparison tests against $x^c$ for appropriate $c$.)

Comment: Thanks, awesome explanation!

Comment: One more question, why is the numerator on the order of $1/v$ and not 1 similar to the denominator?

Comment: @Tyrone The numerator is a constant times $1/x$; the denominator is a constant plus a term that is going to zero as $x \to \infty$. So the numerator is going to zero and the denominator is not. (Whenever you talk about "order" it is always relative to some limit.)

Comment: I agree that the numerator is going to zero, then why did you say that is on the order of $1/x$, I am little confused...

Comment: @Tyrone "The numerator is on the order of $1/x$" means that if you divide the numerator by $1/x$ then you get a quantity which remains bounded and which remains bounded away from zero. In this case the numerator is actually constant when divided by $1/x$. The point of this is, as I said, for comparison tests, because (for $s \geq 0$ and $a \leq 1/2$), the expression in my post is bounded below by $\frac{(1-2a) s}{(1+s/\gamma) x}$ and bounded above by $\frac{(1-2a) s}{x}$. This lets you formulate comparison tests depending on the exponent.

Comment: More clearly (getting your specific constants out of the way), the integrand is between $c_1 x^{2/\alpha - 2}$ and $c_2 x^{2/\alpha - 2}$, for constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ (which depend on $a$, $b$, and $\gamma$, but not $\alpha$.)