# For what values is my integral diverging or converging?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Is the following integral convergent

$$\int_{\gamma}^{+\infty} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{1+sv^{-1}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\alpha_1}v^{\frac{2}{\alpha_1}-1} \, e^{-\beta\, v^{\frac{1}{\alpha_1}}   }+ \frac{1}{\alpha_2}v^{\frac{2}{\alpha_2}-1} (1- e^{-\beta\, v^{\frac{1}{\alpha_2}}})\right)\, dv $$

I know it looks hideous. I am not looking to solve it, in fact I will solve it numerically using MATLAB. I am just looking to know if it converges or diverges.

let us assume $1>\beta>0, \alpha_2=4$. Note that $s$ is not a function of $v$.

If $\alpha_1=2$ does the integral converge? What about when $\alpha_1=3$ what happens to the integral then?

**Update:**

Please check the two different answers provided below.
Thanks

Comment: If all the parameters are positive, then the largest term is equivalent to $\frac{s}{\alpha_2} v^{2/\alpha_2 - 2}$, so the integral converges if and only if $2/\alpha_2 - 2< -1$, i.e. $\alpha_2 > 2$.

Comment: so $\alpha_1=2 $ does not work?

Comment: If $\alpha_2 = 4$ and $s,\beta,\alpha_1 > 0$, then the integral is convergent.

Comment: @user208259 is there any formal way you can guide so I can prove the convergence, or any reasoning?

Comment: Since the integrand is positive, to evaluate convergence you can replace it with a simpler one that is equivalent to it as $v \to +\infty$. Now $1 - 1/(1 + sv^{-1}) \sim sv^{-1}$ as $v \to + \infty$, so you can replace that factor with $sv^{-1}$. Generally, the integral of any term of the form $v^c e^{-dv^{f}}$ will converge, so long as $d,f > 0$. So the only term left that you need to worry about is $sv^{-1}\cdot (1/\alpha_2)v^{2/\alpha_2 -1}$. For that you use the fact that an integral $\int dv/v^p$ converges if and only if $p > 1$.

Comment: You ought to simplify $\alpha_{1}/2$ as 1 everywhere...it cleans things up a bit...

Comment: $\alpha_1$ is not given..

Comment: @user208259  thanks but may i ask why is $1 - 1/(1 + sv^{-1}) \sim sv^{-1}$ as $v \to + \infty$?

Comment: Let $x = sv^{-1}$. We have $x \to 0$. So $1/(1 + x) = 1 - x + o(x)$.

Comment: do you want to write your answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Just an outline of an answer.

I assume that all the parameters $\gamma$, $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\beta$ and $s$ are positive.

All the terms with exponential factors have integrals that converge. The only term left to consider is
$$[1- 1/(1 + sv^{-1})](1/\alpha_2)v^{2/\alpha_2 - 1} \sim (s/\alpha_2)v^{2/\alpha_2 - 2}.$$

The integral therefore converges if and only if $2/\alpha_2 -2 < -1$, that is, if and only if $\alpha_2 > 2$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it diverges.

If $\beta, \alpha_1, \alpha_2 > 0$,
then the exponential terms
all have integrals that converge,
so the only term that matters is
$v^{\frac{2}{\alpha_2}-1}
$.
But
$\frac{2}{\alpha_2}-1
> -1$,
so its integral
diverges by comparison with
$\frac1{v}$
(i.e.,
$v^{\frac{2}{\alpha_2}-1}
=v^{\frac{2}{\alpha_2}}v^{-1}
> \frac1{v}
$).

Comment: but $\frac{2}{\alpha_2}-1=\frac{1}{2}-1=-\frac{1}{2} >-1$

Comment: My bad. The inequality does go the other way. It still diverges.

Comment: can you please give me your opinion the answer provided in the comments

Comment: @martycohen Are you taking into account the $1 - 1/(1 + sv^{-1})$ factor?

Comment: @martycohen thank you for your answer, I was thinking about it, do you think that you have missed the factor outside as user208259 stated?

Comment: I might have. Feel free to submit a corrected answer.